# How to import a csv file into MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, import, export

I am very new to MySQL. I have started learning MySQL today only.

I have been given a task.

In this task I need to create a sample csv file in excel and then upload it on MySQL server, then make some changes and then write it back as a csv file on the hard drive.

I looked up many links available on internet but they are too complicated to understand.

Can somebody explain it to me in simple words assuming that I am a beginner and I just know how to create a connection on MySQL.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php
$csvFile = 'test_data.csv';
$csv = readCSVFile($csvFile);
if(!empty($csv))
{
    foreach($csv as $file)
    {
        //inserting into database
        $query_insert = "insert into csv_data_upload set
            name    =   '".$file[0]."',
            value   =   '".$file[1]."'";
        echo $query_insert;
        $insert = mysql_query($query_insert);
    }
} else {
    echo 'Csv is empty';
}
//Reading CSV File
function readCSVFile($csvFile)
{
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    while (!feof($file_handle) )
    {
        $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $line_of_text;
}
?>
```

And for writing CSV File, Try this,

```
<?php
$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
foreach ($list as $fields)
{
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend uploading the data via Microsoft Access. Access is just like Excel part of the office suite from microsoft. You can easily import the CSV / Excel file via a wizzard. Then use the database wizzard to upload everything to MySQL.

By the way you could probably do the same changes to the data in MS Access. It runs with some adaptations the same SQL commands and you could also use the GUI. I would recommend MySQL more for on line purposes, not for stuff you can do off line. And lets be fair using a command line might not be for everybody the most easy point of entry to databases. There are more using friendly command line alternatives for MySQL, for example mysql workbench and phpmyadmin. You could use them to directly import in to MySQL, but I have no experience with that option.

Good luck with you task.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your code what you have tried, even you can search over google before posting question. Suggested link to check - http://www.php-guru.in/2013/import-csv-data-to-mysql-using-php/